# Numpy Import Issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I'm trying to run some code that uses the numpy library, but with only the statement

```
>>>import numpy
```

i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 137, in <module>
    import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 9, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from type_check import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 8, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import multiarray
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 no es una aplicaci¾n Win32 vßlida.
```

I already done the numpy installation as follows:

```
pip install numpy
```

at the command line, and everithing was fine.

What's wrong?

I have 64 bits Windows 10 and python 2.7.13

Thanks!!

Comment: It's tough to install on windows. I would download the binary from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) and do `pip install the_file_name.whl` (probably `pip install numpy‑1.13.3+mkl‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl` from a cmd in the downloads directory)

Comment: You probably need to uninstall your existing numpy first

Comment: thanks!!!! @roganjosh   It worked!!!!!

Comment: Windows is tough with a lot of scientific libraries. Remember that site and look for them there first tbh, save yourself the headache.

Comment: Just search "python unofficial binaries" if you haven't bookmarked the site.